# pyopencl.cffi_cl.RuntimeError: clenqueuendrangekernel failed: OUT_OF_RESOURCES

Tags: python, opencl, pyopencl

I'm new to pyopencl and opencl generally, so it's not surprising I've gotten to a point with this project where I'm officially stuck. Why am I getting the title error when I run this code?

Code:

```
from __future__ import division

import numpy as np
import pyopencl as cl

from time import time
import sys

from math import sqrt

ctx = cl.create_some_context()
queue = cl.CommandQueue(ctx)
mf = cl.mem_flags
prg = cl.Program(ctx, """
__kernel void rmse(__global const float* x,
                   __global const float* y_true,
                   __global const float* params,
                   const ushort numPoints,
                   __global float* result)
{
    __local scratch[512];
    int numPointsPerThread = (512 + numPoints - 1)/512;
    int start = 512*numPointsPerThread;
    int end = (start + numPointsPerThread < numPoints) ? start+numPointsPerThread
                                                       : numPoints;
    for(int i=start; i<end; i++)
    {
        float y_i = -y_true[i]; float x_i = x[i];
        for(int k=0; k<100; k++)
            y_i += sqrt(pow(x_i, params[k]) + params[k]);
        scratch[i] = y_i*y_i;
    }

    barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);

    for(int numThreads = 256; numThreads > 1; numThreads >>= 1)
    {
        if(get_local_id(0) < numThreads)
             scratch[get_local_id(0)] += scratch[get_local_id(0)*2+1];

        barrier(CLK_LOCAL_MEM_FENCE);
    }

    if (get_local_id(0) == 0) *result = sqrt(scratch[0]/(float)numPoints);
}
""").build()

# Run the experiment
if len(sys.argv) != 2:
    print ("Wrong number of arguments!")
    print ("Usage: GPU #RMSE_evaluations")
    print ("(#data_points is taken from test.csv)")
    sys.exit(1)

numEvals = int(sys.argv[1])

#data = np.genfromtxt("test.csv", delimiter=',', dtype=np.float32)
data = np.full((1000,2), 42, dtype=np.float32)

x = np.array(data[:,0],dtype=np.float32)
x_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=x)

y_true = np.array(data[:,1],dtype=np.float32)
y_true_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=y_true)

result_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.WRITE_ONLY, 4)

start = time()
param_indices = np.arange(0,100,1, dtype=np.float32)
RMSE = np.empty(numEvals, dtype=np.float32)
for i in xrange(numEvals):
    params = np.sin(param_indices*i)+1
    params_g = cl.Buffer(ctx, mf.READ_ONLY | mf.COPY_HOST_PTR, hostbuf=params)
    prg.rmse(queue, (512,), (512,),
             x_g,
             y_true_g,
             params_g,
             np.uint16(len(x)),
             result_g)
    cl.enqueue_copy(queue, RMSE[i], result_g).wait()
    params_g.release()
end = time()

print("Sum RMSE:", np.sum(RMSE))
print("Time elapsed (s):", end-start)
print("Time per RMSE evaluation (s):", (end-start)/numEvals)
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out: The correct call is `prg.rmse(queue, (512,), (1,),`, setting the global workgroup size to 512 makes 512 workgroups, not 512 threads, which overwhelms the device.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same error. It took me forever to fix it. Initially I thought it was a overloading problem so I tried to reduce the load on K80 Nvidia GPU. Code worked fine when working on 1000 transactions. Error occurred with 73,000 transactions.
The real problem is with using memory out of bounds of actual declared array. In C its hard to track such a problem. Pyopencl wont give any error for such a mistake when dealing with small number of transactions. 
In my case I had a while loop with index increment for an array.

```
int indx1=0; int array1[10];
int indx2=0; int array2[100];

//WHILE LOOP
while(indx2<size_of_array2)
{ indx1++; }

//AFTER WHILE LOOP
array1[indx1]=10;
```

Since both arrays are of different size, indx1 was often >10 and that caused the error.

Hope it helps someone.